# Crystal Reports link to data using a url

Tags: crystal-reports

Help much appreciated.

How do I link to data through a url in Crystal Reports.

I can do this in Power BI using 'Get Data' - 'Web' and them pasting in the url.

I can't see how to do it in Crystal.

An example of the type of url I am using is

https://anexample.netdesk.com/api/Report/176f91y1-cd72-47g6-9fgh-dcff77657ga9

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports 2016 you can do this by opening the Database Expert, then expand "Create New Connection", then expand "XML and Web Services".  The window that opens will then have a radio button you can select that is labeled "User HTTP(S) Data Source".

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tried this and can't get it to work for https://whitelight.nethelpdesk.com/api/ReportData/139f91f1-cd72-44c6-9ebc-dcff78887ba5  this url should readily be available and is in Power BI. Any ideas?